# Invalid paramether in Image.FromStream(MemoryStream)

Tags: c#, image, memorystream, networkstream

im trying to send an image via network stream, i have a sendData and Getdata functions
and i always get an invalid parameter when using the Image.FromStream function

this is my code :
I am Getting the pic from the screen, then converting it to a byte[]
Inserting it to a Memory stream that i send via a networkStream.

```
    private void SendData()
    {
        StreamWriter swWriter = new StreamWriter(this._nsClient);
        // BinaryFormatter bfFormater = new BinaryFormatter();

        // this method
        lock (this._secLocker)
        {
            while (this._bShareScreen)
            {
                // Check if you need to send the screen
                if (this._bShareScreen)
                {
                    MemoryStream msStream = new MemoryStream();
                    this._imgScreenSend = new Bitmap(this._imgScreenSend.Width,   this._imgScreenSend.Height);
                    // Send an image code
                    swWriter.WriteLine(General.IMAGE);
                    swWriter.Flush();

                    // Copy image from screen
                    this._grGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, this._sizScreenSize);
                    this._imgScreenSend.Save(msStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    msStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    // Create the pakage
                    byte[] btPackage = msStream.ToArray();

                    // Send its langth
                    swWriter.WriteLine(btPackage.Length.ToString());
                    swWriter.Flush();

                    // Send the package
                    _nsClient.Write(btPackage, 0, btPackage.Length);
                    _nsClient.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void ReciveData()
    {
        StreamReader srReader = new StreamReader(this._nsClient);
        string strMsgCode = String.Empty;
        bool    bContinue = true;
        //BinaryFormatter bfFormater = new BinaryFormatter();
        DataContractSerializer x = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Image));
        // Lock this method
        lock (this._objLocker)
        {
            while (bContinue)
            {
                // Get the next msg
                strMsgCode = srReader.ReadLine();

                // Check code
                switch (strMsgCode)
                {
                    case (General.IMAGE):
                        {
                            // Read bytearray
                            int nSize = int.Parse(srReader.ReadLine().ToString());
                            byte[] btImageStream = new byte[nSize];
                            this._nsClient.Read(btImageStream, 0, nSize);

                            // Get the Stream
                            MemoryStream msImageStream = new MemoryStream(btImageStream, 0, btImageStream.Length);

                            // Set seek, so we read the image from the begining of the stream
                            msImageStream.Position = 0;

                            // Build the image from the stream
                            this._imgScreenImg = Image.FromStream(msImageStream); // Error Here
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you're using WriteLine() which adds Environment.NewLine at the end of the write.  When you just call Read() on the other end, you're not dealing with that newline properly.

What you want to do is just Write() to the stream and then read it back on the other end.

The conversion to a string is strange.

What you're doing, when transferring an image, is sending an array of bytes.  All you need to do is send the length of the expected stream and then the image itself, and then read the length and the byte array on the other side.

The most basic and naive way of transferring a byte array over the wire is to first send an integer that represents the length of the array, and read that length on the receiving end.

Once you now know how much data to send/receive, you then send the array as a raw array of bytes on the wire and read the length that you previously determined on the other side.

Now that you have the raw bytes and a size, you can reconstruct the array from your buffer into a valid image object (or whatever other binary format you've just sent).

Also, I'm not sure why that DataContractSerializer is there.  It's raw binary data, and you're already manually serializing it to bytes anyway, so that thing isn't useful.

One of the fundamental problems of network programming using sockets and streams is defining your protocol, because the receiving end can't otherwise know what to expect or when the stream will end.  That's why every common protocol out there either has a very strictly defined packet size and layout or else does something like sending length/data pairs, so that the receiving end knows what to do.

If you implement a very simple protocol such as sending an integer which represents array length and reading an integer on the receiving end, you've accomplished half the goal.  Then, both sender and receiver are in agreement as to what happens next.  Then, the sender sends exactly that number of bytes on the wire and the receiver reads exactly that number of bytes on the wire and considers the read to be finished.  What you now have is an exact copy of the original byte array on the receiving side and you can then do with it as you please, since you know what that data was in the first place.

If you need a code example, I can provide a simple one or else there are numerous examples available on the net.

Comment: I am sending in a write line an reading in a readLine, this is becuse i am sending a message "IMG" so the ReciveData function will now its going to recive an image, and i also send the size of the array in a write line and read it in a readline, i send the array in a write and read it with a read, i dont understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to keep it short:
the Stream.Read function (which you use) returns an int that states how many bytes were read, this is return to you so you could verify that all the bytes you need are received.
something like:

```
int byteCount=0;
while(byteCount < nSize)
{
      int read = this._nsClient.Read(btImageStream, byteCount, nSize-byteCount);
      byteCount += read;
}
```

this is not the best code for the job

Comment: Thank you it does seem like this helps, but now i have a wirder problom, the write method does not send all of the data, how can i fix this ?

Comment: sorry, can't think of a reason why write won't send the entire data. just so you know according to MSDN there is no use in calling flush() on a network stream.